# How to get list of all CUSIPS/ISIN?

Tags: equities, fixed-income, data, funds

I want a list of all CUSIPs/ISINs. It would be nice if they were also categorized (e.g. Bonds/Funds etc). Where can I get such a data?

Comment: I hate to say it, but this is really what Bloomberg is for. Or perhaps you can go directly to Capital IQ, who manages CUSIP. But you definitely will not find a free data source online that lists all CUSIPs.

Answer (score 7):

SEC tends to keep CUSIPS handy:
http://www.sec.gov/divisions/investment/13flists.htm

Comment: Its only published at each end of quarters I think - a more up to date list would be nice

Answer (score 3):

There is a service on the cusip homepage, but I suspect it will cost you money: https://www.isin.cusip.com/isin/IsinServiceLogin.jsp

Answer (score 3):

You won't find this data for free anywhere. Some data-feeds have it. For example, DTN's NxCore product includes CUSIP in their data files.

Answer (score 3):

In Japan we get ISIN data with http://www.isin.org/isin-database

they have free search tool.